GeoServer ImageMosaic resampling method
I want to publish orthophoto images as a WMTS service in GeoServer. I have approximately 4000 ortho images in *.TIFF format without pyramids. How can I change the resampling method of the resulting tiles to bicubic in GeoServer? I changed the default interpolation method in the "Publishing" section of the layer settings, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to set this in SLD?



I believe that setting the default interpolation method either on the layer-publishing or on the WMS settings should do that and if they don't work then there may be a bug. Did you delete the old tiles from the cache when you changed the setting?

Yes, I deleted the old tiles. I also attempted to visualize the layer (imageMosaic) using WMS. The result remains consistent across different interpolation methods. Please see the attached image.

Why would you expect to see a difference at that scale?

Sorry, you were right. There is, however, a very small difference in the final result. When I look at those images in QGIS or ArcGIS Pro, the difference in rendering between nearest and cubic is much greater. Is it necessary to make any adjustments in the SLD?

Nope, the SLD won't make any difference - I would only expect to see differences in palleted images or at very high scales in an orthoimage

I tried generating pyramids using desktop GIS (I used the cubic method) and then publishing the images via GeoServer. It looks much better (I attached an image). However, GeoServer behaves unstably with them. In some areas, it outputs errors like (unable to load granules, coordinate systems don't match, etc.). That's why I prefer not to use pyramids.
